# Python Iterating New Data into nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on a Python Role-Playing game and I have a function to import item data from a text file. The text file is structured as follows:

```
WEAPON 3 sword_of_eventual_obsolescence 6 10 2 0 10
WEAPON 4 dagger_of_bluntness 2 5 3 1 0
WEAPON 5 sword_of_extreme_flimsiness 3 8 3 7 0
```

The data importing goes like this:

```
def items_get():
    import os
    global items
    items = {
        "weapon":{},
        "armour":{},
        "potion":{},
        "misc":{}
    }
    file_dir = ( os.getcwd() + '\Code\items.txt' )

    file_in = open( file_dir, 'r')
    for each_line in file_in:
        line = file_in.readline()
        line = line.split(' ')
        if line[0] == "WEAPON":
            weapon_id = line[1]
            name = line[2]
            attack_min = line[3]
            attack_max = line[4]
            range = line[5]
            weight = line[6]
            value = line[7]
            weapon_data = {
                "name": name.replace('_', ' '),
                "atk_min": attack_min,
                "atk_max": attack_max,
                "rng": range,
                "wt": weight,
                "val": value,
            }
            items["weapon"][weapon_id] = {}
            items["weapon"][weapon_id].update(weapon_data)
```

However, when I print items["weapon"], I get this:

```
{'4': {'wt': '1', 'atk_min': '2', 'atk_max': '5', 'val': '0', 'name': 'dagger of bluntness', 'rng': '3'}}
```

As you can see, there is only 1 item there. On other occasions I have had two even though I actually have 3 items listed. Why is this happening, and how do I get all 3 items in the dictionary?

Thanks! 
:P

EDIT: Here is the data for the potions, in case you were wondering.

```
 elif line.split()[0] == "POTION":
        _, id, name, hp_bonus, atk_bonus, range_bonus, ac_bonus, str_bonus, con_bonus, dex_bonus, int_bonus, wis_bonus, cha_bonus, wt, val = line.split()
```

A healing potion looks like this in the file:

```
POTION 1 potion_of_healing 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.1 2
```

Comment: `items["weapon"][weapon_id]=weapon_data` would save you a line of code.

Comment: Great weapon names `sword_of_eventual_obsolescence`

Comment: Also, `_, weapon_id, name, attack_min, attack_max, range, weight, value = line.split()` rather than writing out each index manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for each_line in file_in:
    line = file_in.readline()
```

`each_line` already contains the next line, because iterating through a file-like object (say, with a for loop) causes it to go by lines.

On each iteration of the loop, the file pointer is advanced by one line (file-like objects, though rewindable, keep track of their last-accessed position), and then before anything is done it gets advanced once more by the `readline()`, so the only line that doesn't get skipped entirely is the middle one (4).

To fix this, use the loop variable (`each_line`) within the loop body directly and nix the `file_in.readline()`.

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked and it only took me 10 seconds to fix!

Answer (score 0):

**@noname1014**, I know you know this but I want to point out few of the problems with your code (that may occur in some special cases, e.g if you change your file name `items.txt` to `new_items.txt`, `rare_fruits.txt` etc.) and some suggestions.

> Do not use `\` as path separators in Windows. Use `\\` otherwise you may get into problems. `\Code\time_items.txt` will be evaluated as `\Code    imeitems.txt` because `\t` is TAB here.
>
> Using `\` only works in few cases  if `\` followed by any character `A`, `p`, `n`, `t`, `"`, `'` etc. does not construct escape sequences like `\n`, `\t`, `\f`, `\r`, `\b` etc.

Have a look at the below example for clarification.

```
>>> import os
>>>
>>> print(os.getcwd() + '\Code\timeitems.txt')
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\Code        imeitems.txt
>>>
>>> print(os.getcwd() + '\Code\\timeitems.txt')
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\Code\timeitems.txt
>>>
>>> print(os.getcwd() + '\Code\newitems.txt')
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\Code
ewitems.txt
>>>
>>> print(os.getcwd() + '\\Code\\newitems.txt')
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\Code\newitems.txt
>>>
>>> # Do not use it as it may work only in some cases if \ followed by any character does not construct escape sequences.
...
>>> os.getcwd() + '\Code\items.txt'
'E:\\Users\\Rishikesh\\Python3\\Practice\\Code\\items.txt'
>>>
>>> # Use \\ as path separators
...
>>> os.getcwd() + '\\Code\\items.txt'
'E:\\Users\\Rishikesh\\Python3\\Practice\\Code\\items.txt'
>>>
>>> print(os.getcwd() + '\Code\items.txt')
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\Code\items.txt
>>>
>>> print(os.getcwd() + '\\Code\\items.txt')
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\Code\items.txt
>>>
```

> If your dictionay is huge and you are facing any issue while looking into its items, pretty it using **json** module, it has a function called `dumps()` which is used to pretty print `list` and `dictionary` objects.
>
> It is ok to place `import` statements inside function but placing it on the top is a **Pythonic way** (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). It is good for large applications with multiple functions in the same module.
>
> Use **with** statement for opening files, in this case you do not need to close files.

Your code is fine, I have just modified it as below.

```
import os
global items
import json

def items_get():
    items = {
        "weapon":{},
        "armour":{},
        "potion":{},
        "misc":{}
    }

    # Do not use \ as path separators in Windows. Use \\ (\t, \n, \' have speacial meanings)
    file_dir = ( os.getcwd() + '\\Code\\items.txt' )

    with open( file_dir, 'r') as file_in:
        lines = file_in.readlines();
        # ['WEAPON 3 sword_of_eventual_obsolescence 6 10 2 0 10\n', 'WEAPON 4 dagger_of_bluntness 2 5 3 1 0\n', 'WEAPON 5 sword_of_extreme_flimsiness 3 8 3 7 0']

        for each_line in lines:
            # Use strip() to remove any leading/trailing whitespaces (\n, \t, spaces etc.)
            line = each_line.strip().split(' ');

            if line[0] == "WEAPON":
                weapon_id = line[1]
                name = line[2]
                attack_min = line[3]
                attack_max = line[4]
                range = line[5]
                weight = line[6]
                value = line[7]

                weapon_data = {
                    "name": name.replace('_', ' '),
                    "atk_min": attack_min,
                    "atk_max": attack_max,
                    "rng": range,
                    "wt": weight,
                    "val": value,
                }
                items["weapon"][weapon_id] = {}
                items["weapon"][weapon_id].update(weapon_data)
    return items 

# Calling items_get() to get dictionary
items = items_get();
# Pretty printing dictionary using json.dumps()
print(json.dumps(items, indent=4))
```

» Output

```
{
    "weapon": {
        "3": {
            "name": "sword of eventual obsolescence",
            "atk_min": "6",
            "atk_max": "10",
            "rng": "2",
            "wt": "0",
            "val": "10"
        },
        "4": {
            "name": "dagger of bluntness",
            "atk_min": "2",
            "atk_max": "5",
            "rng": "3",
            "wt": "1",
            "val": "0"
        },
        "5": {
            "name": "sword of extreme flimsiness",
            "atk_min": "3",
            "atk_max": "8",
            "rng": "3",
            "wt": "7",
            "val": "0"
        }
    },
    "armour": {},
    "potion": {},
    "misc": {}
}
```